# Server select - MySQL / MariaDB

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I have two database servers, MySQL and MariaDB, when I'm trying to connect to my local database on MySQL server, I always get "Connectionfailed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'ruff'". I found out, that my code is connecting into MariaDB server instead of MySQL. I can CREATE and CONNECT to any database on MariaDB.

How can I connect to MySQL server databases?

My code is:

```
// Creating a connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
// Creating a database named $dBName
$sql = "CREATE DATABASE $dBName";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Database created successfully with the name newDB";
} else {
    echo "Error creating database: " . $conn->error;
}
// Connecting to database named $dBName
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dBUsername, $dBPassword, $dBName);

if (!$conn)
{
    die("Connection fail: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}

// closing connection
$conn->close();
```

Comment: your failed message has from the first connect_error or the message at the end of your code ?

Comment: is it real server or hosting in CPanel or alike?

Comment: You've to login to database as `root` user and run `CREATE DATABASE dbnamehere`. It cannot be executed from script from non root user or user without full db access.

Comment: *I have two servers in localhost/PHPMyAdmin, MySQL and MariaDB* Either they use different ports (and you must define correct port number in connection properties) or only one of them works.

Comment: Thank you guys, define port solved the problem. Now I use localhost:3306 for MaiaDB and locahost:3308 for MySQL

Comment: Please add the solution as an answer and not edit the question, this isn't a forum and adding "SOLVED" to the title isn't helpful. You should add an answer and then accept it, which is the Stack Exchange way of marking a question as "solved".

Comment: You're strange person, You already seeing that You're passing same `$servername` variable, also You're saying that Your code does not connect to different databases. Is it hard to see that variables?! Also why to point to error: `Unknown database 'ruff'`? it's distracting people that You know that You have 2 dbs but You don't have `ruff` db.

Comment: Do you see both listed in the phpMyAdmin dropdown on the login screen? I'm not sure what the code block you've pasted has to do with phpMyAdmin, that code isn't from that application. Can you also post your phpMyAdmin configuration file, `config.inc.php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding port number after the localhost solved the problem.

```
$servername = "localhost:3308"; //MySQL
$servername2 = "localhost:3306"; //MariaDB
```